# Change width so height fits in window screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with a responsive site and I want the homepage to not require any scrolling. Right now, it has a header (239px tall) and a footer (94px tall) and then Owl Carousel sliding through images in the middle of the page. The CSS on the Owl Carousel is at 100% width, which shows the whole image. But the way the slider is setup, if I change the container height to be window.innerHeight, it crops the image in the slider (still 100% width).

How can I have the Owl Carousel be a relative height that changes the width to the exact % width so that Header + Owl Carousel + Footer all fit the users browser window without having to scroll?

**EDIT:**

```
<div id="post-111" class="post-111"> 
<div class="sy-box">
<div class="sy-slides-wrap">
<div class="sy-slides-crop">
<ul class="ken-slider">
<li class="sy-slide kenburns""><img alt="" src="image.jpg"></li>
<li class="sy-slide kenburns""><img alt="" src="image.jpg"></li>
</ul>
</div></div></div></div>
```

This is the basic structure of the Owl Carousel. And has the <'header'> of 239px tall and <'footer'> of 94px tall. The images scale to fit the width of the .sy-box, and max-height:none;

Here is a great, very similar example to what I'm working with. Header, footer, Owl Carousel in the middle. How would you take this page and make it fit the screen (without cropping images, simply having them scale so they fit on the page)? http://www.isidrophotographer.com

Comment: Do you have some source code or example for us to work with? Without any source that would mean we have to build something just to answer your question. **(Unlikely)** Please display the relevant source code or some example for us to work with. Thank you.

Comment: Set the height of the Owl carousel like this: `height: calc(100% - 333px);` (where the 333px = 239px header + 94px footer)

Comment: in the css calculate the height of the carousel. For example: .carousel{height: calc(100% - 333px);} 333px is the total height of header and footer. If it doesn't help please add an example of your code or create jsfiddle so that we can see the problem.

Comment: @michael, you can edit your original post

Comment: this is the best i could do based on the info provided. try re-sizing the screen. http://jsfiddle.net/0e51xgqs/1/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, Dan. I may not be describing myself well. I'm needing the image to keep it's aspect ratio, and basically scale the width down. Like for example, on my computer, if I set .sy-box to be 65% width, then that shrinks the image aspect correctly so there are no scroll bars and header/footer fit on the page. of course as I resize my browser, this doesn't change

Comment: @DanBeaulieu I updated the post to include a link to an example. thanks for your help!

Comment: I've added  an answer to your problem with an updated jsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle.net/q6rL4jkk/4](http://jsfiddle.net/q6rL4jkk/4) . I think that JS tool, imgLiquid, may do it. fixed header/footer, and image scales to be as big as it can without skewing in the middle and no scroll bars. Now just need to figure out how to put that on my site.

```
$(function() {    
    $(".sy-slides-wrap").imgLiquid({
        fill: false,
        horizontalAlign: "center",
        verticalAlign: "50%"
    });

});
```

Comment: you really should be able to do it with just css, I'll read through your response and see if I can formulate something better

Comment: Since I'm going to do this slider with Wordpress, ended up finding a great plugin. [Revolution Slider](http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin/2751380) . It's only $18 & you just create a slider & choose the Full Screen option. This will make the slider fill the browser window. The key is they have an OFFSET CONTAINERS option. So I just put in the classes/ID's for my header/footer, and then it included those in the full screen calculations, so I got a header, slider, footer all to fit the window. just set my slide images to be background:contains. Works great!

Comment: and i ran out of characters, but thanks to @DanBeaulieu and others who provided answers!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this would actually be to use vh and vw units in your CSS. Supported everywhere except of course IE is only partial support and opera.

Answer (score 0):

You should make position as absolute and try these ...

```css
.fit{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="fit"></div>
```

Comment: That ends up making the image disappear completely? I updated the original post w a link to an example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q6rL4jkk/4/ . I think that JS tool, imgLiquid may do it. fixed header/footer, and image scales to be as big as it can without skewing in the middle and no scroll bars. Now just need to figure out how to put that on my site or find an easier way

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you'd like your images and divs to respond to the screen size. This is my solution based on what you've said. Hopefully its enough for you to solve your issue. Make sure you try resizing the window to see how your images react.

I would also highly recommend you check into [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0e51xgqs/2/)

css:

```
img {
    width: 100%;

}

.post-111 {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
  }

.sy-box {
    background-color: blue;
    height:500px;
    width:80%;

}

.kenburns {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, Dan. That isn't quite the feature I'm looking for. It's more along the lines of this: http://jsfiddle.net/q6rL4jkk/2/

So no matter which way you shrink/scale the browser window, the image stays as big as possible without scrolling. I may have to see about using that JS from the fiddle link above. that may be my best bet